# For which planets Kepler has formulated his laws?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

Kepler has formulated his three [laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion) of planetary motion around the Sun.

> Did he formulate the laws for all 9 planets or only for a part of them? Say I do not know if all the planets have been discovered at the time.

Comment: Just to be clear, Kepler didn't "formulate" specific laws for each planet. Kepler's laws are true\* for _any_ planet orbiting any star. He and his peers _verified_ that they were true for the planets that were known at that time. [\* ignoring the very slight discrepancies from what is predicted by General Relativity.]

Comment: Egregiously wrong SE. Why did you not consider [HSMSE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: In the Wikipedia article that you linked to, did you see the table titled “Data used by Kepler” listing six planets?

Comment: @G.Smith: You are right, I did not see it. Looks like a final answer.

Comment: Would this be better on [HSMSE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: that data applies only to the third law.

Answer (score 0):

Kepler found his laws by calculating from the differences between the orbits of Earth and Mars. Because of he amount of calculation, and because he employed no assistant, he did not calculate other orbits. Finding that an elliptical orbit fit the Mars data, he immediately concluded that all planets move in ellipses, with the sun at one focus—Kepler's first law of planetary motion. Actually he was fortunate in Mars, because its orbit has a greater eccentricity than most of the others, and probably could not have obtained a result from the available data for any other planet. I think he chose it because it had the most complete data set from Tyho de Brahe's observation. Mercury has greater eccentricity, but he was uncertain of the data, and had he discovered the precession of the perihelion, he probably would have rejected elliptical motions!

Other astronomers tested his ideas for other planets, but it took a while for his laws to become generally accepted, probably only after Newton published the *Principia*.

Comment: I think that to formulate the third law one needs to have data for at least two planets. Otherwise it does not make sense. Am I wrong?

Comment: @MKO, I think you are right. The third law was rather later than the studies leading to elliptical motion. Kepler did not give details on how he found it, but it describes overall properties, not detailed observations of motion.

Answer (score -3):

he formulated them for the known planets, up to Saturn, Uranus, Neptun, Pluto were not discovered but he knew the would apply to any.

Comment: You forgot Uranus.

Comment: Uranus was discovered 1781 by Herschel, Kepler  died in 1630

Comment: I know. It should go in the list of the planets unknown to Kepler, with Neptun and Pluto. As it is now.